# Why is the batch_size in XLNet and Transformer-XL not the first but the second dimension?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, transformer-model

I'm looking into the XLNet and Transformer-XL source code and could not understand, why is the batch_size not the first dimension. Does someone have an idea?
Do you know any other neural network architecture where the batch_size is not the first dimension?